# Closing a circuit a predefined number of times

Tags: circuit-design

I have a bunch of cheap rope lights with a built-in controller with a single button to change the light effect. When the rope lights are plugged in, they turn on and start cycling through the default effect. When the button is pressed, they switch to the next effect, and so on.

The problem is that the lights have no memory. When the power goes off, they default back to their original effect. I'd like to try and construct a circuit to interface with the lights, so that when the power is turned on, the circuit simulates the number of button presses to reach the predefined light effect.

Since the button on the controller just closes some circuit, I assume that all I need to do is find and build a schematic that is able to close the circuit a set number of times. I could probably do this with an Arduino, but I would like something a bit more bare-metal, since I want to replicate this for 5-6 different rope lights, which would be a bit pricey with an Arduino.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need an "Arduino", its just like a development platform. You can use just an micro-controller, like the one used in some Arduino, ATMega328P, or one of lower cost, just a bit more or not, than you need for a discrete solution.

Anyway, yes that's overkill for using a micro-controller, you can use a CD4017 counter or other family, and a oscillator, can be with a 555 or other IC, or you can do it with discrete components, like transistors, and just use one of the CD4017 outputs to stop the oscillator, you can then use the oscillator pulses to close the contacts on the controller.

But that can be difficult, its not always easy to interface to the other circuit.

Other question, is that you need a low voltage DC (near 5V, depending on your circuit).

- Can you get it from the controller? Does the controller will support the additional current demand?
- If not, for low cost you can do a non-isolated one, but I can presume
  that in the ambient this is used, it will present some danger, so you
  need a isolated power supply.

Like the other answer, if you have engouth knowledge of the circuit in question (that don't need to be a micro-controller), you can try to put a battery on it to preserve its state, a more elegant solution if you know the circuit of the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I actually have built something similar to this in the last year. The problem was to modify a remote control so it could be controlled by an external circuit to provide an additional feature. Since we had no data on the remote control itself, the simplest solution was to use an AVR tiny13 (I think: don't have one nearby) microcontroller to drive an optoisolator that was connected across a pushbutton on the remote. I used isolation because the remote control's switch inputs were matrixed and so couldn't be grounded directly.

You could do something similar here. The micro would record the number of presses (or store a predetermined set in memory) and then drive the existing switch input either directly or through isolation.